# Simple Hangman game

Tags: java, beginner, hangman

It randomly gets a word from an array of `String`s. It prints out a '`_`' char for every letter of the word, displays the ones you have already guessed and displays the ones you have missed.

Some advice would be welcome, such as what I should change, avoid and so on.

Main class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Game game = new Game();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    char guess;

    game.initializeGame();
    do {
        System.out.print("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n\nWord: ");
        game.showRow();

        System.out.print("\n\nMisses: ");
        game.showMisses();

        System.out.print("\nGuess: ");
        input = keyboard.next();

        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
            break;
        else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("new"))
            game.initializeGame();
        else {
            guess = input.charAt(0);
            game.checkRow(guess);

            if (game.isLooser()) {
                System.out
                        .println("\nGame Over!\nYou have missed 8 times!\nThe word was "
                                + game.getSecretWord()
                                + " ! \nThe game will now reset!\n");
                game.initializeGame();
            }

            else if (game.IsWinner()) {
                System.out
                        .println("\nCongratulations!\nYou have guessed the word!\nThe game will now reset!\n");
                game.initializeGame();
            }

        }

    } while (true);

    System.out.println("\nThank you for playing !");
    keyboard.close();
}

}
```

Game class

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Game {
Random random = new Random();
StringBuffer misses = new StringBuffer("");

private final String[] wordArray = { "baboons", "beavers", "cats",
        "chickens", "choughs", "dolphins", "eagles", "elephants",
        "flamingoes", "giraffes", "grasshoppers", "hedgehogs", "hornets",
        "kangaroos" };
private String secretWord;
char[] hangman;

public void initializeGame() {
    setWord();
    setRow();
    misses.delete(0, misses.length());
    System.out.println("\nNew game started! Type \"exit\" to stop game or \"new\" to reset !\nOnly the first letter in youre input will be considered a guess.\nYou have 8 guesses !\n");
}

private void setWord() {
    secretWord = wordArray[random.nextInt(wordArray.length)];
}

private void setRow() {
    hangman = new char[secretWord.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < secretWord.length(); i++) {
        hangman[i] = '_';
    }
}

public void showRow() {
    for (int i = 0; i < hangman.length; i++)
        System.out.print(hangman[i] + " ");
}

public void showMisses() {
    System.out.println(misses);
}

private boolean isCharInWord(char guess) {
    for (int i = 0; i < hangman.length; i++) {
        if (secretWord.charAt(i) == guess)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void changeRow(char guess) {
    for (int i = 0; i < hangman.length; i++)
        if (secretWord.charAt(i) == guess)
            hangman[i] = secretWord.charAt(i);
}

private void addToMisses(char guess) {
    misses.append(guess + " ");
}

public void checkRow(char guess) {
    if (isCharInWord(guess)) {
        changeRow(guess);
    } else
        addToMisses(guess);

}

public boolean isLooser() {
    if (misses.length() / 2 > 7)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public boolean IsWinner() {
    for (int i = 0; i < hangman.length; i++)
        if (hangman[i] == '_')
            return false;
    return true;
}

public String getSecretWord() {
    return secretWord;
}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Remember that any function of the type

```
def function(arg):
    if condition(arg):
        return True
    return False
```

can be shortened to:

```
def function(arg):
    return condition(arg)
```

You can apply this advice to:

```
public boolean isLooser() {
    if (misses.length() / 2 > 7)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Also I think that you can simplify the condition to:

```
misses.length() > 14
```

---

The function:

```
public boolean IsWinner() {
    for (int i = 0; i < hangman.length; i++)
        if (hangman[i] == '_')
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Can benefit from built-ins:

```
public boolean IsWinner() {
    return hangman.indexOf('_') == -1; // '_' never occurs
}
```

As well as this one:

```
private boolean isCharInWord(char guess) {
    return secretWord.indexOf(guess) != -1;
}
```

**Brace yourself**

Please always use braces, doing so increases readability and reduces stupid-bugs probability.

**A bit of generality**

`setWord` is specific to this game, I would do:

```
public void randomChoice(array) {
    return array[random.nextInt(array.length)];
}
```

and then in the initialization I would call:

```
public void initializeGame() {
   secretWord =  randomChoice(wordArray);
   // ...
}
```

I think my version is more immediate to understand.
(By the way, I can see that it is an array, so you can remove that from the name, a simple `words` would be better).

Comment: You should always use the simplification that you mention with `misses.length() / 2 > 7` there, as division is **extremely** taxing on the processor. Also you missed a semicolon on this line: `return hangman.indexOf('_') == -1`.

Comment: @EBrown Nice joke about the division :). One division takes a millionth of a second on a PC, my simplification was only for readibility.

Comment: It's not a joke. Division is **much** more taxing on the processor than multiplication of an inverse. (I'm basing this off of an AMD instruction set document I have, which states that a 64-bit division operation has a latency of 47, whereas a 64-bit multiplication operation has a latency of 6.)

Comment: @EBrown It can be as taxing as you want, let's suppose a division takes a 1/1000-th of a second (**huge** time, but let's just suppose) in a program with a user interface, the user won't notice that time-out. You are rigth about low level number-crunching thought.

Comment: Indeed, I never stated it would be a *noticeable* optimization, merely that, from a mathematics standpoint, the division operation is slow. This is a good answer, nonetheless.

Comment: Also, `return (secretWord.indexOf(guess) != -1;` has an extra parenthesis. :)

Comment: @EBrown excellent that we agree, but it should be clear that writing more complex code to save 0.0001 seconds in a user-interface-driven program is crazy.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (misses.length() / 2 > 7) return true;

System.out.println("\nGame Over!\nYou have missed 8 times!...");
```

The numbers `7` and `8` are not only hard-coded, but they have an important relationship as well. If you decided to change your `7` to `6`, you'll need to remember to change your output above too to say `You have missed 7 times!`. It is better if your `Game` class has a `static final` field to mark this:

```
public class Game {
    private static final int MAX_TRIES = 7;
}

// usage
return misses.length() / 2 > MAX_TRIES; // after refactoring

System.out.println("\nGame Over!\nYou have missed " + (MAX_TRIES + 1) + "times!...");
```

Your `IsWinner()` and `isLooser()` method names can be improved, since a game is *technically* neither a winner nor loser, but won or lost. Therefore `isWon()` or `isLost()` may be better names here.

You also have inconsistent usage of `{ }` braces for your `if` statements, I will suggest using them throughout. This is mainly because it eliminates the possibility of introducing bugs when you have introduced a second line seemingly within an existing `if` block, but is actually not.

The indentation of your methods are also weirdly left-aligned, and I'm not sure if this is a side-effect of using the Markdown formatting. Please check the indentation of your code too.